# How to get the matching data from two tables?

Tags: laravel

I'm used to compare 2 data, one data has an id and the other data is the one that needs comparing to get the matching datas. see code below.

```
DB::table('requests')->where('reqItem',$inventory->invItem)->get();
```

The code shown above displays all requests information that equals to the compared inventory item.

Now what i want to do now is to compare 2 tables without any id (ex. $inventory->invItem). I don't know how to ask this question but i  hope you get what i mean. The figure below shows the way i wanted it to be.

[image]

Comment: Why don't you use eloquent? You would save yourself from using joins.

Comment: used db helper already, if i change it to eloquent that'll just waste my time, but thanks for the suggestion, i'll use eloquent on my next project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run this query. Here, 'inventory' is the name of second table (change it accordingly)

```
DB::table('requests')
        ->join('inventory', 'requests.reqItem', '=', 'inventory.invItem')
        ->select('inventory.reqItem')
        ->get();
```

Comment: Thank you so much, you saved my life :'(